# NGINX: Is it possible to disable cache and redirect request to another server for certain header?

Tags: caching, nginx, header

We are trying to disable nginx cache for specific header, in "Modify Header" chrome extension (you may use other) I added header like: "**X-Dev = 1**" and want to catch this header in nginx.conf to disable nginx cache and proxy request to developer server, is it possible to do?

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass

Comment: Alexey, I forgot to specify that I also need to proxy the request to another server.

Comment: And so what? How proxy_cache_bypass prevent proxying?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found solution, as Alexey recommended I added $http_x_dev header to proxy_cache_bypass directive and point requests to other server by condition:

```
proxy_cache_bypass $http_x_dev;

location / {
    if ( $http_x_dev = 1 ) {
        proxy_pass http://DEV_SERVER_IP:80;
        break;
    }

    ...
}
```